# Rails 4 - Building Multiple Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a user creates a new booking record, part of the data entered is an email address. This email address is used to create a new guest record at the same time if they don't already exist. The booking should have the guest id as part of the record.

In my models I have defined the relationships so:

```
accommodations has_many bookings
guests has_many bookings
bookings belongs_to accommodations
bookings belongs_to guests
```

This is what I have so far in the create action of my BookingsController:

```
...
def create
  accommodation = current_user.accommodation    
  @booking = accommodation.bookings.build(post_params)
  @guest = accommodation.guests.build(params[:email])

  if @booking.save  
    flash[:success] = 'The booking has been added successfully.'  
    redirect_to :controller => 'bookings', :action => 'index'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
...
```

My questions are:

- Should I use 'build' twice as I want the new booking to have the guest id?
- How can I check if guest exists already using email?
- Is it safe/secure to use params[:email] when building the guest?

Comment: And the reason why the new guest may be different from the current user is that they might be booking for someone else?

Comment: users and guests are different - users create bookings on behalf of guests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using `@guest` in the view, there's no need for it to be an instance variable. So:

```
accommodation = current_user.accommodation
guest = Guest.find_or_create_by(:email => params[:email])
@booking = accommodation.bookings.new(post_params.merge(:guest_id => guest.id))
```

You don't need to use `build` in your `#create` method because its main use is to maintain association ties with objects that still don't have a primary key. But since you're persisting your stuff in here, we can go with good old `new` from Ruby.

Comment: ah - I didn't realise you could merge like that - I thought you had to leave it to Rails to add the foreign keys. Also trying to get my head around the line current_user.accommodation as this seems to go against the relationship as accommodations have more that one users

Comment: Well, I just put that line in there because you wrote it. :)